# Get DNS request from service

Tags: android

Is it possible to capture the current dns request via a service in android? I would like to drive some logic in my backend process depending on what URL the user is currently trying to access.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Is it possible to capture the current dns request via a service in android?

Fortunately, no, as this would be a privacy violation.